# Go Kafka router based on https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go library

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I want to work with Kafka in Go, using https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go, but it's complex, since there should be a router implemented. For now I see the only one solution, which is implement a router by yourself.

I would like to register routes with a simple API, like it works in the HTTP router with https://github.com/gorilla/mux library:

```golang
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/articles", ArticlesHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

But based on the topics and events.

Are there actually already exist routers for Kafka in Go? I tried to search, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Note that "router" is a HTTP concept and a priori has nothing to do with Kafka which has nothing to do with HTTP.